# Redis on windows server: no config file specified

Tags: windows, redis, chocolatey

I installed redis using chocolaty. Then, It was working normally, however I cannot start it again.

**Running redis-server**: reports a problem in config file

[image]

**Specifying Config File**

[image]

Running the command:

[image]

But the problem persists, if I try connecting to the client:

[image]

Answer (score 14):

You could follow this page https://redis.io/topics/config

Try to start with the below command

redis-server --port 6380 --slaveof 127.0.0.1 6379

Answer (score 5):

I think you have to run `redis-server.exe redis.windows.conf` in your command prompt and it will work. I think the windows version needs you to specify the config file for it to work (which you can see is in the same directory)

Answer (score 2):

**redis-server --port 6380 --slaveof 127.0.0.1 6379**

[image]

https://developer.redis.com/create/windows/

https://github.com/microsoftarchive/redis/releases

[image]

https://linuxhint.com/install-run-redis-windows/
https://hackthedeveloper.com/how-to-install-redis-on-windows-10/

Answer (score 0):

redis-server --port 6380 --slaveof 127.0.0.1 6379 it happened when i tried it too

Comment: This isn't any different from the highest rated answer.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem in Windows 10 and Windows 11
I am using Angular , Redius , ASP.NET Core sometime the Port is used so I just write these two commands in PoweShell on Adminstration Mode "run as administrator"

```
net stop winnat
net start winnat
```